# ./configure stops progressing on 'checking whether make sets $(MAKE)...'

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to build OpenModelica from source, first ran `autoconf` then `configure`, it descends into the OMCompiler directory then stops, never returns yes or no for that make check.

Can I disable or hard code something in the configure file (or an autoconf file that generated the configure file) to debug this, or skip over it?

Comment: Add the commands you've run and their outputs to the post to make it easier for others to look into it.

Comment: Do you *need* to run `autoconf`?  If there is already a `configure` file in the source distribution then you should avoid running `autoconf`, and go straight to `./configure`.  If there is not already a `configure` file, or if some other AutoTools component or output is missing, then you should still avoid running `autoconf`, and instead use `autoreconf`.  Specifically, `autoreconf -if` is usually the best bet in such situations.

Comment: There are just `configure.ac` files provided, I'll try out `autoreconf -if`